# Qual a diferença entre "string" e "character" em Python?

Tags: python, string

Qual a diferença entre a *string* e *character*?

Por exemplo:

```
print 'Olá, mundo!'

print "Olá, mundo!"
```

Sendo que as duas na teoria são a mesma coisa, certo?

PS.: eu abri o XML para fazer minha edição de cor, e no XML do Python vem uma cor para *string* e uma cor para *character*.

Quando eu utilizo as aspas duplas fica uma cor e aspas simples muda. Mas só que roda normalmente.

Comment: Aí tem duas *strings*.

Comment: Eu sei que aí tem duas strings. Só que na documentação xml do python, o comando para `string` vem de uma cor, no caso `" "` e character vem com outra cor, no caso `' '`.

Comment: Do site https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm Python does not support a character type. Entao aparentemente Python nao tem um tipo character, apenas string.

Comment: E o recomendado no Python sao aspas simples.

Comment: Hum,,, entendi! Obrigado, e gostei do site tb.

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Comment: Sinceramente, eu não entendi o que ele quis dizer com "*vem uma cor para string e uma cor para character*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Python, *string* é uma sequência de caracteres, enquanto *character* é um único elemento dentro de uma string.

Em outras palavras, uma string é uma coleção de caracteres. Por exemplo, a string "pedro" consiste de 5 caracteres: 'p', 'e', 'd', 'r', 'o'.

O Python não tem o tipo de dados "char". Em vez disso, o tipo de dados para um único caractere é "string" de comprimento 1, por exemplo, "a" ou "B".

Embora seja possível tratar strings de comprimento 1 como caracteres, eles são, na verdade, objetos de string em Python.

### E qual a diferença de usar aspas simples (') vs aspas duplas (") ?

Em Python, aspas duplas (") e aspas simples (') são ambas utilizadas para delimitar strings. Não há diferenças funcionais entre elas, o que importa é que o tipo de aspas utilizado na abertura e fechamento da string sejam iguais.

Isto permite que uma string possa conter aspas do outro tipo, por exemplo: "Oi, ele disse: 'Olá!'".

Além disso, aspas triplas (''' ou """) são usadas para strings multilinha.

### Usar aspas duplas ou simples tem algum impacto na performance?

Não existe diferença de performance significativa entre aspas duplas e aspas simples em Python. **O desempenho não é afetado pela escolha do tipo de aspas utilizado para delimitar uma string**.

A escolha entre aspas duplas e aspas simples é geralmente baseada em convenção de codificação ou preferência pessoal do programador.

O importante é manter a consistência ao longo do código e escolher um tipo de aspas e usá-lo de forma consistente.

Answer (score 8):

Python não tem o tipo `char` ou algo parecido, tem apenas *strings*, se deseja ter um caractere apenas use um *string* que só tenha um caractere. Se deseja um valor número que é equivalente a um caractere use um tipo numérico que armazene o número da tabela de caracteres.

Se estiver comparando com C ou outras linguagens semelhantes que usa apóstrofes para delimitar o tipo `char` e aspas para delimitar *strings*, então em Python isto não faz sentido, ambas notações são iguais e podem ser usadas livremente desde que sigam o par, não pode abrir com e tentar fechar com outra. Isto é útil para usar o próprio caractere delimitador dentro de uma *string* sem precisar escapá-lo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).